# Writing to an Excel spreadsheet via Microsoft Graph API - Could not obtain a WAC access token

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to update an existing spreadsheet that is located in the root of a Business OneDrive.

I can run a GET and retrieve the file details.

I'm authorised as an Application as opposed to Delegated.

Whenever I run the following POST:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/demo.xlsx
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AccessDenied",
    "message": "Could not obtain a WAC access token.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "07422c42-930f-4329-809a-93103bff3ab4",
      "date": "2020-05-14T18:32:46"
    }
  }
}
```

I also have Files.ReadWrite.All set to the Application.

I have been using the following documentation for help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0

Apparently sessions are not mandatory, and by default they are persisted - which is what I want (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/workbook-createsession?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

I have ran the GET and POST requests via Postman

Answer (score 0):

One of the following permission scopes is required to use the Excel resource:

```
Files.Read (for read actions)

Files.ReadWrite (for read and write actions)
```

You need to add this permission and give the admin consent:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I already had that enabled, however it seemed to have worked when I gave permissions from within my Business OneDrive, for the files to have access via the graph explorer. I do not believe this was mentioned in any of the documentation?